# How can I use auto code completion in netBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans for java and I cannot use auto code completion. It doesn't work and just shows 'no suggestion' statement when I hit Ctrl-Space. How can I solve it?

I use jdk1.8.0_251 and netBeans 11.3. Here are screenshots of the Sources and Javadocs tabs.

**Sources tab:**

[image: SourcesTab]

**Javadoc tab:**

[image: JavadocTab]

Comment: As it stands your question will probably be closed due to a lack of details. You need to update it with the following information: [1] In NetBeans go to **Tools > Java Patforms** and select the JDK you are using from the _Platforms_ pane. Then take screen shots of the _Sources_ and _Javadoc_ tabs. [2] State the versions of your JDK and NetBeans.

Comment: I modified it! Thank you.

Comment: OK. [1] There is definitely a problem with the backslash character not being rendered correctly in the `Platform Folder` field for those two tabs. I think that is why code completion is not working for you, but I don't know how to fix it. Do you have any idea why that is happening, and can you fix it? [2] Since you are using Windows, what is your locale? [3] Is the backslash being rendered correctly in the `Platform Folder` field on the _Classes_ tab?

Comment: [1] I don’t have any idea why that happens. It worked well at first... [2] It is korean(korea). [3] I am new at programming so I don’t understand what you said. How can I check that the backslash is rendered correctly in the Platform Folder field? (The letter similar to ‘w’ in the picture and the backslash character are on the same keyboard key in Korea.) When I type the backslash key in the source editor, a red line appears. Other grammatically incorrect codes do not appear error until they are compiled. 

I am not good at English. I hope you can understand...

Comment: OK. It looks like the [WON SIGN](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20a9/index.htm) is being rendered for backslash in NetBeans beacause you are using a font that supports Korean characters. See [What is the real meaning of the “Select a language for non-Unicode programs…” dialog?](https://superuser.com/a/131393): _"when set to Korean language for non-Unicode programs '\' (backslash) is replaced with '₩' (Korean currency symbol)...All file paths are delimited by '₩'."_. I don't think that there is a solution for that, and I'm not even sure that it is causing your problem.

Comment: The problem has been resolved when I deactivate Java SE plug-in and reactivate it. Thank you :)